# Can I read the result of a Vue command in a web page using Octave's urlread or webread?

Tags: vue.js, octave, urlread

I can get the HTML text of a web page that displays text I'd like to download. But that text is accessed in the HTML using Vue :

```html
<div class="[margin string]">
<p class="[text formatting string]" v-html="result.summary.text">
</p>
</div>
```

Is there any way I can access the contents of result.summary.text thru urlread or webread?

I'm using Octave 6.2.0.

I accessed the HTML of the web page using "contents=urlread('')", where  is the web page's URL in plain text.  Using webread produced the same results, the HTML text of the web page.

The only thing I could think of to try was "contents=urlread('/result.summary.text')" which just returns the original web page's HTML.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: User @Koen Hollander emailed me a suggested edit, apparently the "<p class=...>" line in my post splits over 2 lines on some screens, but not mine.  He suggested that I put the code text in a box with a slider on it.  I don't use StackExchange very much, so I don't know how to do this, and there's no apparent way for me to reply to his email to ask him how, and I didn't see a way to send an email to him on his profile.  Can anybody help???

Comment: Also, I just noticed that my comment that starts with "I accessed the HTML..." has a formatting error, probably something I typed was interpreted differently by the post parser, so I'll use different special characters.  The fragment "using "contents=urlread(")", where is the web page's URL" should read "using "contents=urlread("<URL>")", where <URL> is the web page's URL".  How do I edit my original post?  I see no Edit button to click on.